# I have a code that has some items and its pricings, i am supposed to print out the words that is below certain price

Tags: python

```
price = {"table": 120, "chair": 40, "lamp": 14, "bed":250, "mattress": 100, "pillow": 10, "shelf": 70, "sofa": 400}
```

I have tried like

```
if price <= 100:
    print(price)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `for` loop that will check the `if` condition and then print.

```
prices = {"table": 120, "chair": 40, "lamp": 14, "bed":250, "mattress": 100, "pillow": 10, "shelf": 70, "sofa": 400}


for thing in prices:
    if prices[thing] <= 100:
        print(thing, prices[thing])
```